# Notificações de medalhas Portuguese Language beta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Ainda não recebemos notificações quando uma nova `medalha` fica disponível no profile do Portuguese Language beta.

Comment: podes marcar a resposta como certa?

Comment: Done @JorgeB.,!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As notificações para medalhas de bronze são suprimidas para utilizadores veteranos. Fazemos isto para prevenir que os utilizadores que já sabem utilizar o site sejam inundados com uma série de notificações sempre que criam uma conta num outro site e ganham algumas medalhas.

São considerados utilizadores veteranos aqueles que recebem o bónus de associação quando criam uma conta no site.

Comment: +200 de rep então certo?

Comment: [Yup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138113/208518).